# TWiki: How to freeze/snapshot a set of pages

Tags: twiki

We're looking to use our TWiki as part of our development process.  As we produce releases of our product, we will create a master release page for the current tool.

The goal is that at any time, someone could start from this page and produce an identical version of the current release.

Is it possible to 'tag' TWiki pages?  (By 'tag' I am referring to the sense as it is used in the versioning of source code).

The only way I can see to do this is to hard code revision tags into the links between pages, although that in itself will be very difficult to maintain.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution, using revisions, is to include a table at the top of each page where the released product version links to a specific *revision* of the current page that is appropriate for that release.  Something like:

```
| *Release*                                           |
| [ [http://twiki/Page/rev=1.7] ][Product 4.0 -]]     |
| [ [http://twiki/Page/rev=1.4] ][Product 2.0 - 3.0]] |
| [ [http://twiki/Page/rev=1.2] ][Product 1.0]]       |
```

An advantage of this is that a modification to a leaf page does not require links to that page to be updated.  The readers select the product version they are interested when they navigate to the page.

This is a similar technique to that used in other documents where they say:  For the most recent version of this document see *http://www.mypage.com/README*.